# find distance to reference items with numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate the distances from a set of points to a set of reference points, where the number of references is different (and smaller) than the number of points. Think, for instance, the distances between locations to the center of the city in which they are located, or age differences between kids and their parents (so each parent has a different number of kids). It is by no means a requirement to use `pandas` but I thought that would be easy and fast.

Given a dataset:

```
np.random.seed(4)
n = 10
city = np.arange(n)
location = city % 6
city = city // 6
x, y = np.random.random((2,n))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([city,location,x,y]),
                  columns=['city','location','x','y'])
# df:
#    city  location         x         y
# 0   0.0       0.0  0.967030  0.779383
# 1   0.0       1.0  0.547232  0.197685
# 2   0.0       2.0  0.972684  0.862993
# 3   0.0       3.0  0.714816  0.983401
# 4   0.0       4.0  0.697729  0.163842
# 5   0.0       5.0  0.216089  0.597334
# 6   1.0       0.0  0.976274  0.008986
# 7   1.0       1.0  0.006230  0.386571
# 8   1.0       2.0  0.252982  0.044160
# 9   1.0       3.0  0.434792  0.956653
```

objects are grouped by index, and objects with `location=0` correspond to the references. So I want to calculate the distances for all objects with `city=0` to the one with `city=0 & location=0` and similarly for `city=1` (and so on for larger datasets). So the following works:

```
dist = np.zeros(city.size)
for i in np.unique(city):
    group = (city == i)
    ref = group & (location == 0)
    dist[group] = ((x[group]-x[ref])**2 + (y[group]-y[ref])**2)**0.5
```

but takes awfully long, of course (I have of order a million "cities" and >10^8 "locations"). I tried applying a distance function to the group, thinking that this would take each bin and calculate the distance to its own reference, since there is always only one reference per city:

```
def fdist(group):
    return ((group['x']-group['x'][group['location'] == 0])**2 \
        + (group['y']-group['y'][group['location'] == 0])**2)**0.5

by_index = df[['x','y','location']].groupby(df['city'])
dist = by_index.apply(fdist)
```

but it only estimates the distance of the reference objects with themselves:

```
print(dist.values)
# array([  0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,
#    nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,
#    nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please fill this out to a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  That second block of code uses column names out of context, and fails to run.  I don't want to code my personal suppositions while I'm trying to debug your function.

Comment: @Prune my apologies. I wanted to give less abstract names to the variables ("city" and "location" rather than "index" and "rank") and failed to see I only did it half way

Comment: Please make *sure* your code executes ... `index` is now undefined.

Comment: sorry! pushed Edit too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I traced the problem -- just to show you the basic debugging:

```
def fdist(group):
    print("TRACE X")
    print(group['x'])
    print(group['x'][group['location'] == 0])
    print(group['x'] - group['x'][group['location'] == 0])

    return ((group['x']-group['x'][group['location'] == 0])**2 \
        + (group['y']-group['y'][group['location'] == 0])**2)**0.5
```

The output is clear:

```
TRACE X
6    0.067974
7    0.673067
8    0.843953
9    0.644029
Name: x, dtype: float64
6    0.067974
Name: x, dtype: float64
6    0.0
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Your term `group['x'][group['location'] == 0]` is another NumPy row:, not a scalar.  Thus, when you subtract, you get an element-wise subtraction, rather than the scalar subtraction you wanted.  The matching element is 0, and the others are undefined.

Exercise for the reader: how do you extract the right hand value from that row `6    0.067974`?  Your alternative is to make an entire array, replicating that row 4 times.